# Mongoose 6.0.5 $push typescript errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

When I updated to the latest mongoose version 6.0.5, updating with $push gives me the following error. The query and update still work, when I was using mongoose 6.0.1 I wasn't getting this error.

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(filter: FilterQuery<INotifications>, update: UpdateQuery<INotifications>, options: QueryOptions & { ...; }, callback?: ((err: CallbackError, doc: any, res: any) => void) | undefined): Query<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ notificationReplyTravaux: IReplyTravaux; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(filter: FilterQuery<INotifications>, update: UpdateQuery<INotifications>, options: QueryOptions & { ...; } & ReturnsNewDoc, callback?: ((err: CallbackError, doc: INotifications, res: any) => void) | undefined): Query<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ notificationReplyTravaux: IReplyTravaux; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(filter?: FilterQuery<INotifications> | undefined, update?: UpdateQuery<INotifications> | undefined, options?: QueryOptions | null | undefined, callback?: ((err: CallbackError, doc: INotifications | null, res: any) => void) | undefined): Query<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ notificationReplyTravaux: IReplyTravaux; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(2588, 5): The expected type comes from property '$push' which is declared here on type 'UpdateQuery<INotifications>'
index.d.ts(2588, 5): The expected type comes from property '$push' which is declared here on type 'UpdateQuery<INotifications>'
(property) $push?: undefined
```

Schema

```js
import mongoose, { PopulatedDoc } from 'mongoose';
import { IArchivedOrder } from './ArchivedOrders.model';
import { IReplyTravaux } from './ReplyTravaux.model';

export interface INotifications extends mongoose.Document {
  user: string,
  notificationReplyTravaux: PopulatedDoc<IReplyTravaux & Document>[],
  notificationOrder: PopulatedDoc<IArchivedOrder & Document>[],
}

const NotificationsSchema = new mongoose.Schema<INotifications>({
  user: String,
  notificationReplyTravaux: [
    {
      type: String,
      ref: 'ReplyTravaux',
    },
  ],
  notificationOrder: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'ArchivedOrders',
    },
  ],
});

export default mongoose.model<INotifications>('Notification', NotificationsSchema);
```

IReplyTravaux interface

```
export interface IReplyTravaux extends mongoose.Document {
  _id: string,
  message: string,
  author: {
    id: string,
    name: string,
  },
  travaux: string | ITravaux,
  createdAt: Date,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. To resolve mine I had to remove `@types/mongoose` as a dependency, as of 5.11.0 the mongoose package has their own types.